# How can I change a format of an exported java object into a file?

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to export java object into a txt file, but the output in that file is not well formated and contains unnecessary data. If someone could tell me what am I doing wrong. So this is the simple example of the code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String shortName;
    private String fullName;


    public Test(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName=shortName;
        this.fullName=fullName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }
    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name:" + shortName +   "\nFullName: " + fullName;
    }

}
```

And this is a part of the method:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        Test test = new Test("Short name of test","Full name of test");
        o.writeObject(test);
        o.close();
        outputStream.close();
```

And this is what I get in the file:

```
¬í sr &com.testing.project.Evaluation.model.Test        L fullNamet Ljava/lang/String;L     shortNameq ~ xpt Full name of testt Short name of test
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Java Serialization which writes the object into its own binary format, not text. If you need text format, I would suggest you use JSON, with a library such as [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).

And here is a working example for your convenience (which both writes to a text file and reads back from the text file to an object):

Main.class

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Test test = new Test("Short name of test","Full name of test");
        om.writeValue(new FileOutputStream("test.json"), test);

        Test readValue = om.readValue(new FileInputStream("test.json"), Test.class);
        System.out.println(readValue.getShortName());
        System.out.println(readValue.getFullName());
    }
}
```

Test.class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String shortName;
    private String fullName;

    public Test() {

    }

    public Test(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName=shortName;
        this.fullName=fullName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }
    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name:" + shortName +   "\nFullName: " + fullName;
    }
}
```

Notice that I've added a default constructor to Test.class so that Jackson can create it while deserializing from json.

Answer (score 1):

The writeObject function writes the object graph of Test to the file stream. It is used for persistence in JAVA. If you want to store field data to a file I suggest to use a dedicated method in your class using FileWriter.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectOutputStream` will not write in readable format. You probably want to use a `FileWriter`:

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"))) {
        Test t = new Test("Short name of test", "Full name of test");
        writer.write(t.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This works great, it writes it in the readable format, thank you a lot.

Comment: Not a very good approach. 1) This relies on the toString( ) method which is not dynamically changed as you add new fields. 2) Also the semantics of toString( ) are not to provide a serialization format. 3) You cannot read back from text file to object without extra custom code to parse the text file.